# Replacing RMagick with mini_magick with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, rmagick, minimagick

I'm using `RMagick` and loving it, but it is eating up **huge amounts of memory**. Even a simple script would use over 100MB of Ram. On my local machine this isn't a problem, but on heroku my app crashes when a few users simultaneously upload Pictures.

I found [mini_magick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) and trying to replace it in my Model's, but can't find a solution. This is my current Process Flow:

```
  # Validations
  validates :scr, presence: true

  # Paperclip
  has_attached_file :scr,
    styles: {
      index:        ['220x170#', :jpg, quality: :better],
      show:         ['1000', :jpg, quality: :better],
      original:     ['100%', :jpg, quality: :better],
      directionals: ['115x70#', :jpg]
    },
    convert_options: {
      show:         '-quality 90 -unsharp 3x0.4+0.4+0 -interlace Plane',
      index:        '-quality 90 -unsharp 3x0.4+0.4+0 -interlace Plane',
      original:     '-quality 90 -interlace Plane',
      directionals: '-quality 90 -interlace Plane'
    },
    processors: [:thumbnail, :compression]

  # Paperclip Validation
  validates_attachment_content_type :scr, content_type: ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png']
```

How can i replace RMagick and let Mini_magick do the Magic ?

Answer (score 2):

remove Rmagick from gemfile.add [minimagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) to your gemfile and start using it

```
Add the gem to your Gemfile:

gem "mini_magick"
```

---

```
bundle install
```

---

```
####now start using it with callback/observer 
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("input.jpg")
image.resize "100x100"
image.write  "output.jpg"
```

---

### OR

you can use  [delayed_paperclip](https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/) for the same so that at runtime convert only those styles that you need on next page....rest put it in background for conversion using it without changing the code.

```
 process_in_background :avatar, :only_process => [:show,:original,:directionals]
  ##assuming you next page only need style :index..
```

Comment: :) I'm struggling on how to implement it to my current Settings and to use it properly with Paperclip. For Example: How can i use image_magick for the styles and convert options ?

Comment: @TheMiniJohn you can give it a try for delayed_paperclip..as you need performance..i have updated my answer

Comment: Sounds promising, will give that a try. But i still need to get rid of RMagick, that beast eats memory for breakfast!